# How to fix compile error with unexpanded parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates

I get a error for an unexpanded parameter pack while expanding it.

This code is for testing purposes.

Later i want to call a differrent function with the head, tail and element.
I need the element to call another template function and want to maintain the other argument to later call a different template function.

Current output of clang (version: 8.0.0)

test.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <int... Tail>
class for_each_type {
    public:
    template <int element, int... Head>
    int each() {
        for_each_type<Tail..., element> _for;

        _for.each<Head...>();
        return element;
    }

    template <int element>
    int each() {
        return element;
    }
};

int main() {
    for_each_type<> _for;

    std::cout << _for.each<1, 1, 2, 2>() << std::endl;
}
```

I expect the code to output `6`, but the actual output is a error message.

To run start the compiler i just run `clang++ test.cpp`

The current error message is:

```
C:\Users\HP\Documents\GitHub\CPP-Game-Engine\src>clang++ test.cpp
test.cpp:10:23: error: expected ';' after expression
        _for.each<Head...>();
                      ^
                      ;
test.cpp:10:9: error: expression contains unexpanded parameter pack 'Head'
        _for.each<Head...>();
        ^         ~~~~
test.cpp:10:23: error: expected expression
        _for.each<Head...>();
                      ^
3 errors generated.
```

Comment: TL;DR: `_for.template each<Head...>();`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Not sure if we want to dupe close this as it is only half the problem.  Even after using `template` it wont compile because the function call is ambiguous when only one template parameter is used.

Comment: also `template <typename = void> void each() { }` as ground case for recursion (removing the version with only one `int` parameter).

Comment: @NathanOliver I figured the dupe was good enough, since it solves the one error OP was stuck on. Feel free to reopen if you think the question deserves a more complete answer.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat After more though I'll leave it.  The ambiguity issue is a duplicate as well so we can add it here if the OP needs it.